# Problema radius no Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Deixei o formato arredondado, porém quando Clico no botão ele retorna para o formato padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

após o click o botão fica quadrado novamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia. Você precisa incluir o código responsável por essa interação, apenas olhando assim não será possível te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Boa! Está utilizando app:cornerRadius ? Utilizo desta forma e funciona da api 21 até a 28 (apis testadas no app em questão)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="@string/entrar"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
    android:background="@color/colorOrange"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:cornerRadius="20dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"/>
```